# How can a Flash Player app in a browser export a video to a user's computer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash app that runs in a desktop browser that allows the user to create animations with sounds. I want to allow the user to save their animations (movieClips they assembled) to their computer in a common video format. Is this possible? How would I go about it?

Search results are more about encoding Flash in authoring or encoding a video stream.

Comment: Create animation, pass it to the server in POST request, let server encode it into video format (if not encoded on client side) and pass the video back to user as a server response with specific header that will activate the download window.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Anyway to do this with a ByteArray and not involve a server?

Comment: It's not about ByteArray, it's about security. You cannot save any locally-generated content from the browser app.

Comment: What @AndreiNikolaenko wrote you is incorrect. You are absolutely right there with the byte array. You could just take the movieclip, draw every frame of it as a bitmap, then create a video from these bitmaps (that will be quite some work) and then use FileReference.save().

Comment: OK! So can I make an executable program with ByteArray and save it on user computer?

Comment: Don't know. You certainly can save document files such as pngs and jpgs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use FlashyWrappers library to encode movieclip frames and microphone audio to an .ogv file though it supports mp4 too. FlashyWrappers produces a byte array of the compressed video which is then saved using FileReference.